# Better way to repeat queries instead of UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query that would output a particular row, multiple times. Let's say to output a row 6 times. I've checked other questions that relate to this, but didn't get any one that best answers my question. 
Here's my query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1
```

This method will work for a small number of repetitions. Now my question is, is there a better (or standard) way of doing this, which will also work for large repetitions?

If this question has been answered before, kindly drop the link, and I'll give it a go.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you want repetitions? if you really want that then duplicate them in a table to select.

Comment: I want to use the detail as default to fill in *empty* slots. Do I really have to duplicate them if they are up to 100 or 200? My main goal is to maintain the same ID throughout the query.

Comment: Post your sample table(s) and the expected result.  May be that could clarify your task.

Comment: The reason why I need this is because I am creating an advert portal, which will have 6 slots (*for now*). For a banner to be displayed in the advert slots, it has to be active. I already have a query that will display the active banners. What I really want to do is to display default banner if no active banner is found OR if the active banners are not up to six.

Comment: is this mysql? or sql-server?

Comment: this is a little hacky but it does what you want. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4328/1 to be honest what you should do is just duplicate the row in another programming language (whichever one you use to execute the query)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell. Please forgive me if I'm asking. Could you please explain where the `e` came from? I don't really understand what to substitute

Comment: e is the alias I gave the table.. aka `FROM tablename e`

Comment: Okay, thanks. It worked! I've tried to duplicate the rows using PHP, but it's not working, and that's what prompted me to look for a *query* alternative. If you don't mind, can you give an insight on how best to achieve this using php?

Comment: Thanks for your input @RyanVincent. I was referring to my previous comments with John Ruddell.

Comment: samuel i posted an answer with a more concrete way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way to do this is whatever your number of rows you want to have you can make a number table that you select off of and join by your id + the number of rows you want duplicated. like so

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM example e
JOIN
(   SELECT
        seq.s as digit
    FROM
    (   SELECT (hundreds.s + tens.s + ones.s) s
        FROM(SELECT 0  s UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) ones
        CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 s UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT 40 UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION ALL SELECT 60 UNION ALL SELECT 70 UNION ALL SELECT 80 UNION ALL SELECT 90) tens
        CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 s UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300 UNION ALL SELECT 400 UNION ALL SELECT 500 UNION ALL SELECT 600 UNION ALL SELECT 700 UNION ALL SELECT 800 UNION ALL SELECT 900) hundreds
    ) seq
) n ON e.id + 5 > n.digit
WHERE e.id = 1
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4328/5)**

**The problem with the previous sql fiddle I posted (in the comments) is you have to have enough records in the table to pull out the accurate duplicate records.. this way you will get what you want every time**

**NOTE:** for all intents and purposes this is an example. I would **highly** recommend you don't run this query all the time. if you really need a numbers table then create one and insert these values once. then just join the table.

if you must go this route (duplicating records in mysql) then this is what I would do

```
CREATE TABLE digits (id INT);
INSERT INTO digits (id)
SELECT
    seq.s as digit
FROM
(   SELECT (hundreds.s + tens.s + ones.s) s
    FROM(SELECT 0  s UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) ones
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 s UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT 40 UNION ALL SELECT 50 UNION ALL SELECT 60 UNION ALL SELECT 70 UNION ALL SELECT 80 UNION ALL SELECT 90) tens
    CROSS JOIN(SELECT 0 s UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300 UNION ALL SELECT 400 UNION ALL SELECT 500 UNION ALL SELECT 600 UNION ALL SELECT 700 UNION ALL SELECT 800 UNION ALL SELECT 900) hundreds
) seq
```

now that you have a digit table just join on it

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM example e
JOIN digits d ON e.id + 5 < d.id
WHERE e.id = 1
```

Comment: Does this mean that I'll have a duplicate record in mysql? If yes, I do not think I really want to do that. Here's the deal: I have a table where all the advert details are stored (id, title, img_url, ad_url, status) and I already have a function that will query the DB and get the adverts who's status are "active" and then display them in the advert slot. What I really want to achieve is to get the default banner which is also in the DB with id=1, if one or more of the advert slots are empty(i.e if the advert has been deactivated). Will there still be any need to create a duplicate record?

Comment: Like I've been saying you should do this in another programming language

Answer (score 1):

Do a one-time creation of a table with lots of numbers from 1-n, then use that to "generate" as number range and join to that range.

Here's a simple way to create and populate the table:

```
create table numbers (number int not null primary key auto_increment);
insert into numbers () values ();
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
insert into numbers select null from numbers;
```

This code populates the table with numbers 1-1024. Every extra execution of `insert into numbers select null from numbers` doubles the number of rows.

Now the join, say 100 times:

```
select table.* from table
join numbers on number <= 100
where id = 1
```

You can of course parameterise the `100` value as a query parameter, meaning you have one query for how ever many rows you need at runtime.

Because mysql doesn't support generated sequences, the `numbers` table can be very handy for generating ranges of dates and all sort of values.