# How to union multiple times same SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like this

```
select 1,2,3 from dual
union all
select 1,2,3 from dual
```

When I need to add new row, i put another union all, and that's ok. But problem appear when I need several union, for example 20. It is really annoying and not efficient to make another 17 unions. Is there a way (some procedure, function whatever) to make it faster and more elegant?

Comment: SQL is not very good at generating data, but rather querying it and serving out results on data which already exists.  One approach here would be to just generate a flat CSV file with however many rows you want, then use Oracle's loader tool to move it into a table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well I need on this way, for jasper

Comment: There is a similar mysql question posed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402899/better-way-to-repeat-queries-instead-of-union-all - not sure if Oracle will allow something similar..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem, easy-peasy.

```
SQL> select 1, 2, 3
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 10;

         1          2          3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3
         1          2          3

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to use json_table in such cases:

```sql
select *
from json_table(
  '{data:[
     [1,2,3,"abc"],
     [2,3,4,"def"],
     [3,4,5,"xyz"],
    ]
   }'
   ,'$.data[*]'
   columns
      a number path '$[0]',
      b number path '$[1]',
      c number path '$[2]',
      d varchar2(30) path '$[3]'
);
```

Results:

```
         A          B          C D
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1          2          3 abc
         2          3          4 def
         3          4          5 xyz
```

Comment: It's pretty embarrassing I think, that Oracle still doesn't support the standard `values` [row constructor](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=16bb76003083dae0c350c15f0c99321a)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, I often miss it... and generate_series... but considering how CBO is complex already and how many features/transformations/etc it supports, I think that's not so bad to be a bit conservative. At least, I think it's better to have good planner than huge amount of syntax constructions with much more bugs.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on Littlefoot's answer:

```
select 1, 2, 3
from   xmltable('1 to 20');
```